# How to make a docker container act as a relay for another container?

Tags: docker, networking, proxy, vpn

I have two containers A and B living in different nodes that are separated by the internet. They both wants to talk to a service that is also on the internet. Due to network settings, B can't directly talk to the service, but A can.

I wonder if it's possible to make A a relay for B, so that B can talk to the service via A?

Note that the relay must be bidirectional. Both A and B can connect to a port on the service, and the service can also connect to a port on A, and ideally another port on A that gets redirect to a port on B.

I have a few ideas in mind, none of them seems plausible:

1. Use docker overlay network. It seems overlay network can make two container talk to each other in different networks, but I'm not sure if it's optimized for networks that are across internet and even if it is I have no idea how do I make A act as a relay. But if this is possible, please let me know how it can be done.
2. Set up a tcp or udp proxy on A for B to use. I don't know if such thing exists and can work bidirectionally.
3. Make B establish a VPN connection to A, so A will forward B's request to the service. But is it possible to set up VPN inside containers?

Does docker offer other utilities to help with this? How is making a container act as a relay usually implemented? (I guess "relay" might be a wrong term, would love to be corrected if a more suitable term exists.)

Comment: This sounds like the work of a proxy. A container acts as a proxy for B container. 
Please try https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/ to set proxy on B.

Comment: Do proxies support bidirectional communications? What proxy software would you recommend to install in a container?

Comment: Docker doesn't have any special support (or restrictions) in this area; you'd address this the same way you would without Docker.